# iphone : how to make iPhone App seachable in App Store for iPad device?

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store, universal

My app is and iPhone based App, and it can run on iPad device, though UI is designed for 640x960 device.
   When I search the app in iPad, it will show no this app by default. There're two tab in the app store. One is iPad app, the other one is iPhone app. How could I make my app show on these two tabl?
   Because changing app into universal take effort. Is any other methods ?
   I noticed other app uses the same UI like me, but it can show on iPad tab.

Comment: iPhone-only apps don't appear in the iPad app search. This is normal. Your app isn't an iPad (or Universal) app. When a user looks for iPad apps, the goal is to find apps that take full advantage of the iPad.

Answer (score 4):

No there is no easier way than changing it to universal, your app needs to be built for iPad to be displayed in the iPad app section.